# How to measure the lag between Amazon Redshift MVs and MSK topics in an architecture involving Redshift Streaming Ingestion feature?

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, aws-msk

In our architecture we have data from AWS MSK being ingested into AWS Redshift using the [Amazon Redshift Streaming Ingestion](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/redshift-streaming-ingestion/) feature. In this approach, we define an external schema where we have the Materialized Views (MVs) being defined on the topics in MSK cluster. These MVs have auto-refresh turned on.

At any given point in time, what are the design options to measure the lag between the data in the MSK topics and the Redshift Materialized Views i.e. how far the Redshift MVs are the from the kafka topics respectively?